# How to scrape the Cleveland Fed for Inflation data

Tags: web-scraping, google-sheets

This is a question related to scraping a website to Google Sheets.

I am trying to scrape this website: https://www.clevelandfed.org/our-research/indicators-and-data/inflation-nowcasting.aspx

Specifically I am trying to scrape the two tables, called Monthly Inflation Nowcasting and Quarterly Inflation Nowcasting - see picturee below

[image]

I have tried IMPORTDATA,IMPORTHTML and IMPORTXML without success. Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: JS content cant be scrapped

Comment: can be done by excel, not by google sheets

Comment: Would google app script be able to do it?